# Why does this regex not pull out date python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, extract

So I've never really made my own Regex expression before, I've mainly adapted ones I've found. Since I couldn't find any ideas for a method in python I thought I'd give it a go.

I converted a dict to a pandas df using `.items()` to get the name in one column and the other column has produced this:

| Places | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-12 |
| Name 2 | Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-12 |
| Name 3 | Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-09 |
| Name 4 | Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-09 |
| Name 5 | Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-12 |
| Name 6 | Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2006-04-21 |

Since the date I want (2nd date in the string) is after a large white space I added 3 white spaces before the brackets of the date format but all I end up with is NaN values every time. I have tried without specifying those white spaces but still nothing.
My column is an object dtype as I checked and I get no errors which is frustrating?
I feel like there must be something missing but after copious searching and trials I have got no further.

Examples of what I have tried:

```
test['Date'].str.extract(r'\s{3}(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/)', expand=True)
test['Date'].str.extract(r'\s\s\s(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/)', expand=True)
test['Date'].str.extract(r'\s{4}([?=20][1:9]{2}\-[0:9]{2}\-[0:9]{2}/)', expand=True)
test['Date'].str.extract(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$', expand=True)
```

What I would like is the new column to have only the dates:

| Places | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| name 1 | 2021-03-12 |
| name 2 | 2021-03-12 |
| name 2 | 2021-03-09 |

Any suggestions or criticisms to understanding regex expressions would be amazing.

Comment: Can you provide extra rows for the df? Just to make sure the data structure

Comment: I'd highly recommend using https://regex101.com/ to diagnose your regex if you're not too familiar with them

Comment: @ifly6 I have looked at that and I have spent so long trying to break down a solution using a regex. I've also looked at things like https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ to understand what expressions I could use

Comment: Why not something like `df['Dates]=df['Date'].str[-10:]` ?

Comment: @balandongiv I've done that already. I'm looking for a regex answer specifically because I end up using regex's to pull data and if that had a comma at the end i would then need another code to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Thought about what could be wrong and after more tweaking I thought I hadn't specified the  -  should be separate to the digits in the regex

```
test['Date'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{2})$', expand=True)
```

Result:

```
0   2021-03-12
1   2021-03-12
2   2021-03-09
3   2021-03-09
4   2021-03-12
5   2006-04-21
```

I then just added to a new col `test['new_date] = test['Date'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{2})$', expand=True)`

EDIT:
If unsure whether the date is 1 or 2 digits I simply added a comma to specify either or:

```
test['new_date] = test['Date'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}[\-]\d{1,2}[\-]\d{1,2})$', expand=True)
```

I will note that my example is more restrictive than @balandongiv's as extra \w in the string will produce a NaN as I specified $ to show it was the end of the string

Comment: Your solution fail if the days have only one digit. `'Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-9,'` will give `nan`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

split and extract the date

```
place=['Name 1','Name 3']
Date=['Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-12',
      'Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-09,']
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(place,Date)),columns=['place','Date'])
df['new']=df.Date.str.split('N-Rate').str[-1].str.extract(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{1,2})')
```

Comment: I like the str.split() first, I never thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try:

```
>>> df
   Places                                              Date
0  Name 1  Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-12
1  Name 2  Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-12
2  Name 3  Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-09
3  Name 4  Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-09
4  Name 5  Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2021-03-12
5  Name 6  Soil N 2021-02-25 00:00:000 1. N-Rate 2006-04-21
```

### Result:

```
>>> df['Date'].str.split(" ", expand=True)[6]
0    2021-03-12
1    2021-03-12
2    2021-03-09
3    2021-03-09
4    2021-03-12
5    2006-04-21
Name: 6, dtype: object
```

Of beside that if you're looking for `Date` only then use below.

```
>>> df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.split(" ", expand=True)[6]
>>> df
   Places        Date
0  Name 1  2021-03-12
1  Name 2  2021-03-12
2  Name 3  2021-03-09
3  Name 4  2021-03-09
4  Name 5  2021-03-12
5  Name 6  2006-04-21
```